# How to handle table joins for GET and POST requests when using Azure SQL Bindings for C# in Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, .net, binding, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I'm currently experimenting with SQL Bindings for C# Azure Functions for the first time, and I'm unsure what the best practice is when it comes to handling table joins for GET and POST requests.

I'm trying to reduce the queries and requests to the Function App API from the client in hopes to improve efficiency, so I'm using join operators where possible, and also hoping to return the newly created/updated data as a response without making additional requests.

I currently have two classes, 'Booking' and 'Location'. Each booking has a location, and since multiple bookings can share a location, I've created a many-1 relationship in the database with a foreign key in the Booking table.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Sql;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace API
{
  [DataContract]
  public class Booking
  {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("customer_id")]
    public string? CustomerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("location_id")]
    public string? LocationId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("deleted")]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
  }
}
```

As I'd often want to retrieve the location details with the booking, I'd look to make a single query to the database with a join as per my GetBooking function:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Sql;

namespace API
{
  public class GetBooking
  {
    [Function("GetBooking")]
    public static HttpResponseData Run(
      [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "booking/{id}")]
      HttpRequestData req,
      [SqlInput(
        commandText: "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Booking] as Booking " +
                      "LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Location] as Location ON Booking.LocationId = Location.Id " +
                      "WHERE Booking.id = @id",
        commandType: System.Data.CommandType.Text,
        parameters: "@id={id}",
        connectionStringSetting: "SQL_CONNECTION_STRING"
      )]
      IEnumerable<Booking> result
    )
    {
      if (!result.Any())
      {
        return Response.NotFound<Booking>(req);
      }

      return Response.OK(req, result.FirstOrDefault());
    }
  }
}
```

However, since the Booking class doesn't contain the properties of the Location entity, it won't output - unless I inherit the Location class:

```
public class Booking : Location
  {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public new Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("customer_id")]
    public string? CustomerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("location_id")]
    public string? LocationId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("deleted")]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
  }
```

This now leads to another issue, where I can't also inherit the Customer properties if I were to also retrieve them in the same request / query.

And lastly, when trying to create a new Booking using an output binding, I'd have to use a different class with duplicated properties as I haven't yet found a way to tell the function to ignore certain properties on insert.

For example I could create a BookingEntity class for database inserts and updates:

```
public class Booking : Location
{
  [JsonProperty("id")]
  public new Guid Id { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("date")]
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("customer_id")]
  public string? CustomerId { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("location_id")]
  public string? LocationId { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("deleted")]
  public bool Deleted { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
  }
}

public class BookingEntity
{
  [JsonProperty("id")]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("date")]
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("customer_id")]
  public string? CustomerId { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("location_id")]
  public string? LocationId { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("deleted")]
  public bool Deleted { get; set; }
  
}

public class BookingOutput
{
  [SqlOutput("[dbo].[Booking]", "SQL_CONNECTION_STRING")]
  public BookingEntity? BookingEntity { get; set; }

  public HttpResponseData? Response { get; set; }
}
```

And use this for the output bindings, such as my CreateBooking function:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace API
{
  public class CreateBooking
  {
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public CreateBooking(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<CreateBooking>();
    }

    [Function("CreateBooking")]
    public async Task<BookingOutput> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "bookings")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
      Response response = new(_logger, "Creating Booking");

      /* read the body of the request */
      string body = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
      BookingEntity? bookingEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookingEntity>(body);

      /* check that the booking is valid */
      if (bookingEntity is null)
      {
        return new BookingOutput()
        {
          Response = response.BadRequest(req)
        };
      }

      /* generate a new id for the booking */
      bookingEntity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

      return new BookingOutput()
      {
        BookingEntity = bookingEntity,
        Response = Response.OK(req, bookingEntity)
      };
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine, but then I'm only able to return the newley created BookingEntity as the result, rather than the Booking object that includes the Location properties unless I make a separate call to my GetBooking function.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental, or I'm straying away from best practices when it comes to SQL Bindings. How are you supposed to handle query joins for SQL Bindings?

Comment: Ouput bindings overrides the data

Answer (score 0):

I have created two tables `Booking` and `Location`;

```sql
CREATE  TABLE Booking (
 Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
 Date DATETIME, CustomerId NVARCHAR(50), 
 LocationId NVARCHAR(50), 
 Deleted BIT, 
 CONSTRAINT FK_Booking_Location FOREIGN KEY (LocationId) REFERENCES Location(Id) ); 
  

CREATE  TABLE Location ( 
Id NVARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, 
Name NVARCHAR(100) );
```

I was able to fetch details from both table using `join` and I added values in each table using `SqlInput` and `SqlOutput` Respectively.

**#My Directory :**

```
MyAzureFunctionsProject/
│
├── Functions/
│   ├── GetBookingFunction.cs
│   ├── CreateBookingFunction.cs
│   └── ...
│
├── Models/
│   ├── Booking.cs
│   ├── Location.cs
│   └── ...
│
└── Shared/
│   ├── BookingDTO.cs
│   └── ...
│
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
```

**#My Code :**

```cs
// Models/Booking.cs
public class Booking
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}

// Models/Location.cs
public class Location
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Shared/BookingDTO.cs
public class BookingDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

**`Function.cs`:**

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Sql;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using FunctionApp4.Shared;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class Function
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function>();
        }

        [Function("Function")]
        public HttpResponseData Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "Booking/{id}")] HttpRequestData req,
            [SqlInput(
            commandText:"SELECT Booking.Id, Booking.Date, Booking.CustomerId, Booking.LocationId, Booking.Deleted, Location.Name AS LocationName " +
                "FROM Booking " +
                "LEFT JOIN Location ON Booking.LocationId = Location.Id " +
                "WHERE Booking.Id = @id",
            commandType:System.Data.CommandType.Text,
            parameters:"@id = {id}",
            connectionStringSetting:"SQL_CONNECTION_STRING"
            )] IEnumerable<BookingDTO> bookings)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger with SQL Input Binding function processed a request.");
            
            var booking = bookings.FirstOrDefault();

            if (booking == null)
            {
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            var responseData = new
            {
                booking.Id,
                booking.Date,
                booking.CustomerId,
                booking.LocationId,
                booking.Deleted,
                booking.LocationName
            };
            
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.WriteAsJsonAsync(responseData);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**`Function1.cs`:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Sql;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using FunctionApp4.Shared;
using System.Text.Json;
using FunctionApp4.Models;
using Azure.Core.Serialization;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<OutputType> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger with SQL Output Binding function processed a request.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            // Deserialize JSON to BookingDTO
            var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BookingDTO>(requestBody);

            var booking = new Booking();
            booking.Id = data.Id;
            booking.Date = data.Date;
            booking.CustomerId = data.CustomerId;
            booking.LocationId = data.LocationId;
            booking.Deleted = data.Deleted;
            

            var request = new Location();
            request.Id = data.LocationId;
            request.Name = data.LocationName;

            return new OutputType()
            {
                ToDoItem = booking,
                RequestLog = request,
                HttpResponse = req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
            };

            
        }
    }

    public class OutputType
    {
        [SqlOutput("Booking", connectionStringSetting: "SQL_CONNECTION_STRING")]
        public Booking ToDoItem { get; set; }

        [SqlOutput("Location", connectionStringSetting: "SQL_CONNECTION_STRING")]
        public Location RequestLog { get; set; }

        public HttpResponseData HttpResponse { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For `SQLOUTPUT Binding` reference check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql-output?tabs=isolated-process,nodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#http-trigger-write-to-two-tables-c-oop)

## `OUTPUT`:

```bash
Functions:

        Function: [GET] http://localhost:7282/api/Booking/{id}

        Function1: [POST] http://localhost:7282/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-22T07:13:04.228Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000116B5F66'.
[2024-02-22T07:13:57.593Z] Executing 'Functions.Function' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=80be0abc-c71e-4808-b474-04412868e2e9)
[2024-02-22T07:14:02.584Z] C# HTTP trigger with SQL Input Binding function processed a request.
[2024-02-22T07:14:02.705Z] Executed 'Functions.Function' (Succeeded, Id=80be0abc-c71e-4808-b474-04412868e2e9, Duration=5142ms)
[2024-02-22T07:15:43.111Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=c4ececb9-6b1d-47fe-96bf-b1abb53c6a28)
[2024-02-22T07:15:43.141Z] C# HTTP trigger with SQL Output Binding function processed a request.
[2024-02-22T07:15:47.333Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=c4ececb9-6b1d-47fe-96bf-b1abb53c6a28, Duration=4236ms)
```

[image]

**`Booking/{id}`:**

```json
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Date": "2024-02-20T00:00:00Z",
    "CustomerId": "customer123",
    "LocationId": "location123",
    "Deleted": false,
    "LocationName": "aus"
}
```

[image]

**`Function1`:**

```json
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Date": "2024-02-22T00:00:00Z",
    "CustomerId": "customer456",
    "LocationId": "location456",
    "Deleted": false,
    "LocationName": "India"
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vivek, thank you for your answer! Definitely close to what I'm looking for, however I'm trying to avoid duplicating class properties if possible (I accept that there may be no way around this) but most of all I don't want to have to include all the joined table properties in the body of any POST/PUT requests. Would it still be possible to achieve a similar output?

Comment: you want to insert only few selected values through POST in selected tables?